# prove or disprove about the statement for a limit of a sequence

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of numbers such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n+1}=L$. Does this imply that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}=L$?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent

Comment: So does this mean that if a subsequence converges, so does the sequence itself?

Comment: No. Your question has got nothing to do with subsequences.

Comment: what about if $a_{n+1}$ is replaced by $a_{2n}$?

Comment: what do you think

Comment: I think that $a_{n+1}$ is not a subsequence. Am I right?

Comment: It is a subsequence which excludes only the first term of $a_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a limit of a sequence is determined by the "infinite tail" of the sequence.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$ n > N \Rightarrow |a_{n+1} - L| < \varepsilon $$. Take $N+1$, then for every $m > N+1 > 1$ we can write $m = n+1$ and then
$$ | a_m - L | = |a_{n+1} - L | < \varepsilon $$
since $m > N+1 \Rightarrow n+1 > N+1 \Rightarrow n > N$.

Comment: Thanks @LinAlgMan. But does your proof work for $a_{2n}$?

Comment: No. Take $a_{2n} = 1$ and $a_{2n+1} = 0$. Then $(a_n)$ has no limits. The reason is that not any $m \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written as $m = 2n$ (but every $m$ can be written as $m=n+1$).